# how to get parent child hierarchy using stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedure and want to use it for category subcategory hierarchy. I have data stored in single table with column parent_category to distinguish parent or child or subchild. Due to large data I want to use stored procedure but I am not getting how to use the stored procedure. I tried using join but to no avail.
I want data to be displayed as follows.
parent
--child
----subchild and so on.

Any help/suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

When having **NULL** in Parent Value:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY COALESCE(<parent_id>,<id>), <id>), category_parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

When having **ZERO** in Parent Value:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY COALESCE((SELECT NULLIF(<parent_id>,0)), <id>), NULLIF(<parent_id>,0) IS NOT NULL
```

Hope this may help you!